# Clean way to access outer class by the implementing delegate class

Tags: kotlin

I was thinking about such case (accessing outer class which uses current class to implement some stuff):

```
interface Does {
    fun doStuff()
}

class ReallyDoes: Does {
    var whoShouldReallyDo: Does? = null

    override fun doStuff() {
        println("Doing stuff instead of $whoShouldReallyDo")
    }
}

class MakesOtherDo private constructor(other: Does, hax: Int = 42): Does by other {

    constructor(other: ReallyDoes): this(other.also { it.whoShouldReallyDo = this }, 42)

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val worker = ReallyDoes()
    val boss = MakesOtherDo(other = worker)
    boss.doStuff()
}
```

Expected output:

```
Doing stuff instead of MakesOtherDo@28a418fc
```

But can't do that, because of error:

> Error:(15, 79) Cannot access '' before superclass constructor
>   has been called

Which targets this statement: `other.also { it.whoShouldReallyDo = this }`

How can I (if at all) fix above implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is `other.also { ... = this }` expression accesses `this` of type `MakeOtherDo` and is also used as argument to `MakeOtherDo` constructor.  Hence, `this` will be accessed as part of `MakeOtherDo` (unary) constructor before `this` has been initialized as an instance of `Does` (super)class.

Since the assignment does not affect the initialization of the super class, you can executed it in the constructor of `MakesOtherDo` after the super class has been initialized.

```
class MakesOtherDo private constructor(other: Does, hax: Int = 42): Does by other {

    constructor(other: ReallyDoes): this(other, 42) {
      other.also { it.whoShouldReallyDo = this }      
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me a few minutes to decipher what you were doing above, and really the problem has nothing to do with delegates. You can simplify it down to this:

```
class Wrapper(var any: Any? = null)

class Test(val wrapper: Wrapper) {
    constructor(): this(Wrapper(this)) // Cannot access "<this>" before superclass constructor has been called
}
```

The concept of "this" doesn't exist yet when we're still generating arguments for its constructor. You just need to move the assignment into the block of the constructor, which is code that's run after `this` becomes available:

```
class Test(val wrapper: Wrapper) {
    constructor(): this(Wrapper()){
        wrapper.any = this
    }
}
```

Or in the case of your example:

```
constructor(other: ReallyDoes): this(other, 42){
    other.whoShouldReallyDo = this
}
```

Comment: Yeah, right. My main point was to be able to access outer class by delegate, which is not supported by default (as `ReallyDoes` does not have native way to access `MakerOtherDo` instance - kinda a black box in a way). I hoped to create component-like architecture, where logic could be separated with implementation by delegation. Still not happy about `hax: Int = 42` ;(